# Move two divs separately with touch

Tags: html, jquery-ui, touch

So I have two leavers/divs that i want people to be able slide with iPad/Android on website. At the moment I have tried jQuery UIs slider + touch punch to make it (it's basically slider with two handles) but seems I cannot move two handles simultaneously. With one handle at a time it works great but yes, I would need to have it so you move both handles with two fingers same time.

Is there better way to do this then jQuery UI's slider? I don't really need to get any values or anything from it. Just visual stuff. Could touchmove be option? Can I move div using it?

EDIT. hmm, is it even possible? I think iPad for example takes it always as pinch?

Comment: No one have advice really? :/

Comment: Post the code you've so far, preferably along with an online demo... If you're keen on fixing this, then putting a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) is likely to help.